# Export part of data filed - MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, dataframe, csv

I'm using MongoDB Compass to export my data as csv file, but I have only the choice to select which field I want and not elements in a specific field.

MongoDB export data:

[image]

Actually, I'm interested to save only the "scores" for object "0,1,2".

Here a ScreenShot from MongDB Compas:

[image]

It is something that I should deal with python?

Comment: Perhaps write an aggregation pipeline to "select"/project all the data you want and then `"$out'` to a new collection?  Then you could just select everything from the new collection to export.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: @rickhg12hs I'm not sure I got it

Comment: @HanarDept The desired output is a bit ambiguous to me. `only the "scores" for object "0,1,2"` ... Which array do you want to have a max of 3 elements?  ... `"scoreTable"` or `"scoreTable.scores"`?  I added an answer below for the latter.  It's good to show documents in your question before and after some desired transformation.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit In the attached screenshot we have many field (e.g unit, maxScorePerQuestion, scoreTable ...)
In the scoreTable array we have the results for 3 players as we have 3 object (0,1,2). For each object, we have many elements and actually, I want to save only the PlayerName which is a string element and the array score.
I hope that it's clearer :)

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to "rewrite" `"scoreTable"` so that there are a maximum of 3 elements in the `"scores"` array and then `"$out"` to a new collection that can be exported in full.

```js
db.devicescores.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "scoreTable": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$scoreTable",
          "as": "player",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$player",
              {"scores": {"$slice": ["$$player.scores", 3]}}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$out": "outCollection"}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2cXx3HVw4Yo).